# Rolebased content in JavaFX using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, javafx, spring-security

I wonder if it's possible to create rolebased content in JavaFX using Spring Security so that one page was different for different users?
I've read that it is absolutely possible in web, but what about a desktop application?

Comment: It should be possible anywhere as far as you are able to make web calls and get response.

Comment: It is possible, but you have to hard-code quite a lot of behavior in the JavaFX client. Your login web service call needs to return some sort of a list of things that that user can do. Then your client needs to show the available pages/links etc based on that, which is hard-coding.

Comment: @Jai Is there a proper way to do so? I mean, some tutorials. Don't you know?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to use Spring Security in a standalone application. You can check an example in the following article (with JavaFX) :  https://dzone.com/articles/javafx-spring-day-3-%E2%80%93